# Expressing the stack of sheaves with 1-limits

Tags: sheaf-theory, descent

[Zhen Lin's answer to the MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/455810/223002) mentions that $\mathsf{Sh}(-)$ is a stack for the canonical topology on the site of open subsets of a space. [One of the comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455706/gluing-sheaves-can-we-realize-mathcalfw-as-some-kind-of-limit/455810#comment2090564_455810) asks whether the stack descent condition can be realized as a strict 1-limit. Finally, Zhen Lin [writes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455706/gluing-sheaves-can-we-realize-mathcalfw-as-some-kind-of-limit/455810#comment2090772_455810) this is doable, but for a different diagram (though of the same shape).

What are the details? Is this part of a more general story?

Comment: If you want some keywords, look up Reedy fibrant diagrams and homotopy limits.